# Proof by Induction: inequalities and natural numbers.

Tags: inequality, induction, natural-numbers

How can I prove that

For all $n \in \Bbb N$ such that $10<n$ then $0 < n^2 -13n +24$ by induction.

This is what I have so far:

Base Case:

$n = 11$

If $n = 11$ then:

- $0 < n^2 -13n +24$
- $0 < (11)^2 - 13 (11) + 24$
- $0 < 2$

Induction Hypothesis:

$0 < k^2 -13k +24$

Inductive Step:

$0 < (k+1)^2 -13(k+1) +24$

I’m supposed to get to this $2k-12$, but I don’t understand how, and after that I think we need to do something else.

Comment: The same question was asked one hour ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4059529/42969

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove $0 &lt; n^2 -13n +24$ by induction.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4059529/prove-0-n2-13n-24-by-induction)

Answer (score 2):

For the base case $n=11$, $f=121-143+24=1$ so the base case is positive.

Then for $n+1$, we have $f(n+1)=f(n)+2n-14$

Well, clearly $2n>14$ for all $n>11$ so $f$ is strictly increasing, QED.